# JQuery doesn't run parallax when displayed on a page but works with absolute link

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

My parallax works fine with an absolute link but doesn't when it is displayed on my website [using joomla].

How can I fix this issue ? I don't find any conflict.

[Absolute link](http://smashedbird.com/portfolio/parallax/)

[Website link](http://smashedbird.com/golftown-donation-page)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see this error in the console: golftown-donation-page:577 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).localScroll is not a function

Comment: I changed my $( to jQuery( which solved a lot of my issues because Joomla didn't like $(  @AguV

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: localScroll loads for http://smashedbird.com/portfolio/parallax/ but NOT for http://smashedbird.com/golftown-donation-page

Your js file: http://smashedbird.com/portfolio/parallax/scripts/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js is present in both, but you must have something missing. ... That's why.

Comment: They both link to the exact same file [jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js].  The page from the absolute link is injected on my website using Jumi

Comment: You don't have the script on the other page, it is missing, right?

Comment: No, i made sure all the scripts are present.